# Handle relational data in Flutter with MobX

Tags: flutter, relational-database, mobx

I'm new to Flutter and I'm trying to create an app for a personal project. The project is a content sharing platform where you can upload sound files or image files inside Albums that you created.

The backend is written in Django / Django Rest Framework and I have multiple CRUD (one for the albums, one for the works (sound / picture), one for the users and one for the categories. The database is a PostgreSQL.

I got everything working for making the network calls but I'm struggling to structure how to handle the relations between all these objects to avoid instantiating multiple times the same object.

I'm struggling to decide how and where to store my data and if I should separate the UI stores and the data stores....

If you need more information, tell me, I'll update this post with what's needed (models, endpoints documentation,...)

I hope someone has a good advice or want to share what he does !

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

well actually stackoverflow is not the best place to start ;)

What you're asking here is how to architecture your app, I'll put ressources here from where you can start:

- [Medium flutter architecture](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-architectures/home)
- The very rich Brian Egan [github](https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_architecture_samples) with the live demo for each [enter link description here](https://fluttersamples.com/)
- Here's a list of approaches for state management from [flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

This should be a good start !!

And if you're stuck on a very specific point of code please feel free to come and ask ;)